# Find a formula for the power series $H(z) = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty H_n z^n$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, harmonic-numbers

> The harmonic numbers $H_n$ are defined by $H_0=1$ and
> $$H_n = 1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dots+\dfrac{1}{n-1}+\dfrac{1}{n}.$$
> Find the formula for the power series $H(z)=\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty H_n z^n$

This is the first time I encounter the harmonic numbers so I got no idea on how to do this. Can somebody please help me with this? Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: If you know about Cauchy products of power series: $$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {H_n z^n }  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}} } \right)z^n }  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {1 \cdot \frac{1}{k}} } \right)z^n }  = \left( {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{n}z^n } } \right) \cdot \left( {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {z^n } } \right) =  \ldots 
$$

Comment: Thank you. And for $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n} z^n$, I can take the derivative and then take the integral again right?

Comment: Yes, or just look at the [Maclaurin series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) of $-\log(1-z)$.

Comment: Yet another way is to use $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^n a_{n,k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_{n,k}$ (for, say, absolutely convergent series). Incidentally, $\color{blue}{H_0=0}$ is a conventional assumption (supported by $H_n=H_{n-1}+1/n$ at $n=1$).